# Insert data into Hive partition without overwriting existing data

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Lets say I have two local files file1.txt and file2.txt.

Contents of file1.txt:

```
1,a
3,c
```

Contents of file2.txt

```
2,b
4,d
```

I've put the files on Hadoop like this

```
hadoop fs -rm -r /user/cloudera/repart2/*
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/cloudera/repart2/20150401
hadoop fs -put file1.txt /user/cloudera/repart2/20150401/
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/cloudera/repart2/20150402
hadoop fs -put file2.txt /user/cloudera/repart2/20150402/
```

I've made a Hive table

```
# Select a test database
use training;

# Create the table
create external table repart (
col1 int, col2 string)
PARTITIONED BY (Test int)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
location '/user/cloudera/repart2';

# Add partititons
ALTER TABLE repart ADD PARTITION (Test='20150401') LOCATION '/user/cloudera/repart2/20150401/';
ALTER TABLE repart ADD PARTITION (Test='20150402') LOCATION '/user/cloudera/repart2/20150402/';
```

When I do a select statement

```
select * from repart;
```

It shows

```
1   a   20150401
3   c   20150401
2   b   20150402
4   d   20150402
```

I want my table to eventually look like this

```
1   a   20150401
2   b   20150401
3   c   20150401
4   d   20150401
2   b   20150402
4   d   20150402
```

But when I try my insert query

```
INSERT INTO TABLE repart PARTITION (Test='20150401') select col1, col2 FROM repart where Test = 20150402;
```

The query makes the table look like this. The original data in partition 20150401 has been overwritten.

```
2   b   20150401
4   d   20150401
2   b   20150402
4   d   20150402
```

The "hive --version" command returned: 0.12.0-cdh5.0.0. I noticed [this jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3062), but my table is already all lowercase, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The same code ran without issues when I used Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.4.0. It must have been something broken about 0.12. I'll just use the new version. I'd still be interested if someone knows why 0.12.0 broke though.

Comment: I took a long look at it.  Looked at the hive Jira and the language guide and couldn't find anything wrong with it.  Good luck.